# Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 setup blocked

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to install Microsoft visual studio 2015 community it gives me error "setup blocked" and writes "The computer needs to be restarted before setup can continue. Please restart the computer and run setup again"

[visual studio error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKljV.png)

I tried to restart in various ways (for example canceling hibernate), but every time I get the same error. I tried to look it up, but couldn't find any solution that worked for me.

The full log of the error can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/2Ecta6M6).

It might be important to mention, that at the moment I have visual studio 2012 on my computer, but if I try to uninstall it, I get the same error that the computer needed to be restarted.

Thanks.

**edit:**

I found a solution that worked for me (for all who encountered this problem):

http://www.itexperience.net/2009/06/25/bypass-pending-reboot-of-automatic-updates-0x8ddd0007/

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc164360%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to make it more visible to others. There is nothing wrong in answering your own question 

Answer (score 2):

In the registry there is a key (RebootRequired) which tells that you need to reboot your machine.
The problem was that the key existed when it shouldn't have (created on another time, but wasn't deleted afterwards).

By entering to registry and deleting this key, the problem is solved.
You can find the key at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\
```

based on:

http://www.itexperience.net/2009/06/25/bypass-pending-reboot-of-automatic-updates-0x8ddd0007/

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily override "Restart" requirement for Visual Studio installation.

Use
[ignore-restart for Visual Studio](https://puvox.software/blog/visual-studio-needs-to-be-restarted/) .

Comment: This link just redirects to some scammy looking page full of ads. No content.

Comment: @TimHoppen thanks for pointing it out, that domain seemed expired & re-purchased by ad-network. I've updated the link, you can try it now.