# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise uninstall, reinstall, change failure

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Hello everyone i tried to install Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. After the installation, i tried to start the Application and there was the error message:

> "The computer needs to be restarted before setup can continue.Please
>   restart the computer and run setup again.".

I restarted my PC for several times, but every time, i get the same error. I tried to uninstall it, reinstall it, but i get the same error. I attach the log file and the screenshot of the message, i tried also uninstall it following the instructions here `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yw5ahy28bXU`
 but nothing changed. Please help me! Thanks Here is the log file https://pastebin.com/9kHatAxN

Comment: Shot in the dark: try to create a new admin user and log in as this user and try to launch Visual Studio. Just to cross that off as tested. Profile issues and the likes...

Comment: Hi Panos, do you have any updates? If this issue persists, please feel free to let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the warning information, please go to Setting-Windows Update and make sure all pending patches are installed and reboot the computer. Sometimes, the installation of a previous program or Windows update might not complete successfully may be cause this issue, please check [this](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/vs2015/received-error-computer-needs-restarted-setup-can-continue/).

If this issue persists after re-run the VS 2015 installer as administrator, try to shut down your computer not restart, you can go to Control Panel\System and Security\Power Options and click Choose what the power button does, turn off fast startup (recommended).

You can also check [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562653/microsoft-visual-studio-community-2015-setup-blocked) and back up your registry key, delete this key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\ to have a try.